# Modelling cooperative task over a collection of input documents in BPMN (Activiti)

Tags: activiti, bpmn

I need some help in modeling this in BPMN 2.0 (particularly using Activiti, ver. 5.16.3).

The attached diagram suggests that "Revisa planes, aprueba e informa" (review plans, approve and inform) will be executed for each "Plan anual de necesidades" received from CT (centro de trabajo / work center, in this case a school).

[image]

Well, that is wrong. I found out about it after asking the client how exactly this "revisa planes, aprueba e informa" will be done. So here's the thing:

1. This activity is to be performed over a collection of "plan anual de necesidades". That is to say: it waits until all the schools have submitted their plan.
2. This activity is to be performed by a group of people (in the same area), in a cooperative manner..., in the sense that the collection of plans received from schools will be split among those reviewers.
3. At some point that group of people (as a whole) will have to issue one single document ("a condensed plan").

How to model that (and be explicit about those aspects in the process definition)?

Thanks in advance,
Raka

Comment: Should I introduce another role (especially for step 3)? It's the one who are responsible for issuing the approval and "condensed plan". Maybe "director of rm_inter".

Answer (score 0):

If I figure it right, your problem can be solved with multi instance tasks.  [Read more about it.](http://activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnMultiInstance)

Main idea would be to declare task "plan anual de necesidades" as parallel multi-instance  (`isSequential="false"`), also declare your loop cardinality (number of waiting schools) and if you need, assign every parallel task to specific user or role.

For second problem you can also can use multi instance forking by role. All information/variables you should dynamically inject with expression language(EL)

Third statement, for that you can assign one role to be representative or assign multiple users that need to approve document.

Your description is abstract so I tried to be specific. This isn't a trivial problem so probably you will need some time to implement this. Don't forget to put boundary timer events on your user task, you will need them for escalation, for example if user didn't submitted document until some date.

Hope it helps.